# Why doesn't my code work in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript works on Safari 3 but not on newer versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174478/javascript-works-on-safari-3-but-not-on-newer-versions)

The following JavaScript is working with IE but not with Safari/Firefox:

```
function loadframe() {
    var iframeEl = document.getElementById("ifrm");
    if (!iframeEl) {

        var el = document.createElement('<iframe id="ifrm" width="80" height="80" src=\'<!--EP CLASS="com.epiphany.presentation.ServerURLWriter" ACTION="campaign_segment_load" TEMPLATE="campaign\\campaign_segments" -->\' onload="dw_display(\'ifrm\',\'segmentspn\')" ></iframe>');

        document.body.appendChild(el);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can anybody spot the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It's just because you are using it wrong.

`document.createElement` expects a tag name not html code:

```
iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-2141741547

Dom 2 Core Spec:

> createElement
>
> ```
> tagName of type DOMString
>  The name of the element type to instantiate.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The ability to pass a HTML string to `document.createElement()` is an Internet Explorer proprietary feature.  Other browsers do not allow you to do this.

One possible solution would be to create a wrapper element, and set it's `innerHTML` to the HTML string you have there.

```
function loadframe() {
    var iframeEl = document.getElementById("ifrm");
    if (!iframeEl) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = '<iframe id="ifrm" width="80" height="80" src=\'<!--EP CLASS="com.epiphany.presentation.ServerURLWriter" ACTION="campaign_segment_load" TEMPLATE="campaign\\campaign_segments" -->\' onload="dw_display(\'ifrm\',\'segmentspn\')" ></iframe>';

        document.body.appendChild(el);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that your HTML is also invalid — you cannot have a HTML comment inside an attribute.

Comment: Hats off Andy...excellent...Thank you very much...its working in Safari,but not working in mozilla...anyway great help.can we modify it to work in mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not valid. The parameter for document.createElement can only be the tagname, like "iframe". You then have to set the attributes later.

```
document.createElement('iframe');
```

It doesn't work in standards-compliant browsers and won't work in Internet Explorer 9. See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx