# JavaScript works on Safari 3 but not on newer versions

Tags: javascript, safari

The following JavaScript is working fine in older versions of Safari (Safari 3), but not on latest version of Safari.

Can you help me find the problem?

```
function loadframe(){
  var iframeEl = document.getElementById("ifrm");
  if(!iframeEl)
  {
    window.alert('hellooooooo');
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = '<iframe id="ifrm" width="0" height="0" src=\'<!--EP CLASS="com.epiphany.presentation.ServerURLWriter" ACTION="campaign_segment_load" TEMPLATE="campaign\\campaign_segments" -->\' onload="dw_display(\'ifrm\',\'segmentspn\')" ></iframe>';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some explanation of what that bizarre markup is supposed to do. In general, asking simply why something "doesn't work" without saying what **does** happen versus what **should** happen is unlikely to get much of an answer.

Comment: Instead of if(!iframE1) it is better to use if (iframE1 != null && iframE1 != undefined). And please give more explanation about the script and the problem.

Comment: Instead of latest version it is better to mention the exact version number.

Comment: Define "not working" do you get any errors on the JS console (I assume Safari has such a thing).

Comment: You should detail what you want the code to do, and what it actually does. No one is going to start installing several versions of Safari and try to find bugs in your code.

Comment: It's not loading the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function loadframe()
    {
       var iframeEl = document.getElementById("ifrm");
       if(!iframeEl)
       {
         var el = document.createElement('div');
         var e2 = document.createElement('iframe');
         e2.src ="http://google.com";
         e2.setAttribute('id',ifrm);
         e2.width= 80;      
         e2.height= 80;             
         document.body.appendChild(el);
         el.appendChild(e2);
         return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

This will work on all browser, As  iframe is another element, we should add it using DOM's method.